# Count Number of Clicks on Hyperlink on Separate Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to track the number of times a user clicks on a searchable list of hyperlinks.

On Sheet1, I have set up a search box which displays the top three results. To tidy up the interface, I have moved the Search function, Rank function, Title, and Hyperlink to Sheet2. I have included pictures of both below:

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uETOe.jpg) [Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUabc.jpg)

**My Question:**

Is it possible to count the number of times a user clicks on a hyperlink in the results section of Sheet1 and increment a counter next to that hyperlink on Sheet2?

I found the code below, which works if you click the link on Sheet2, but nothing so far that addresses this particular situation.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Selection.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
 ' This Code increases the value of the number by "1",
 ' in the third Cell to the right of the Cell that contains the Hyperlink
 ' for every Hyperlink, on any/every Row.
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try tracking it by counting the number of times the cell with the hyper link becomes the active cell. Make sure to change the active cell once the user clicks it to a count for multiple clicks

Comment: @sourceCode thank you for your insight. Focusing on the active cell set me on the path toward a resolution.

Comment: @sourceCode thank you for your insight. Focusing on the active cell set me on the path toward a resolution.